# Can we Call OnCreate() method from another function

Tags: android, android-studio, oncreate

I am making a simple "Guess the number app". The app generates a random number when it starts, in onCreate() method. And on button click method I wrote a code so the user will enter a number and if the number is correct, the program should again generate a random number.

But when I try to call onCreate() method again from my button's onClick method, I get system crash. Can you help me out on how to call this onCreate method from function? I am posting my code below.

```
package com.amit.higherolower;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int randomNumber;
    public void guessGame(View view){
        String message = "";
        EditText userNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberEditBox);
        String userNumberText = userNumber.getText().toString();
        int userNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(userNumberText);
        System.out.println(randomNumber);

        if(userNumberInt < randomNumber){
            message = "You've  Guessed Lower";
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberEditBox)).setText("");
        }
        else if (userNumberInt > randomNumber){
            message = "You've Guessed Higher";
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberEditBox)).setText("");
        }
        else{
            message = "You're Right Dude, Now let's guess the new number again.";
            onCreate(new Bundle());
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);
    }
}
```

Comment: just create another method and put your `Random randomGenerator = new Random();` and  `randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);` in it. And call that method.

Comment: @Umarov post that as answer, I also think it is best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7150118/5353361 has the right idea, refactor out of `onClose`. Specifically, as Umarov says, take your two lines of non-boilerplate out to another function and call that instead.

Also I tried something like:

```
public static void triggerRebirth(Context context, Intent nextIntent) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourClass.class);
    intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_RESTART_INTENT, nextIntent);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    if (context instanceof Activity) {
        ((Activity) context).finish();
    }

    Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
}
```

from (https://github.com/JakeWharton/ProcessPhoenix) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345538/5353361